# How to programmatically upload an APNs (apple push notification key) authentication key to Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to find a way to upload an APNs authentication key to Firebase Cloud Messaging programmatically, but I haven't been able to find any documentation or examples for doing so.

Currently, I am uploading the authentication key manually through the Firebase console by going to the Cloud Messaging tab, selecting my iOS app, and then uploading the key under the "Apple app configuration" section.

However, I would like to automate this process as part of my app deployment pipeline. Is there a way to upload the APNs authentication key programmatically through an API provided by Firebase?

I am using the Firebase Admin SDK in nodeJS to interact with Firebase, but I couldn't find any method in the documentation to upload the APNs authentication key.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

[image: no description]